# Is there a term or expression for elements that are aligned like a watch face?

Tags: phrase-requests

When you arrange elements in a circle, you can either keep the initial orientation of each element, or align them similarly to a watch face.

[image]

Is there a term for elements that are aligned like a watch face (right)?
I tried to go with "Elements are aligned outward" or "Elements are facing outwards", but it doesn't sound right and is very vague.

Comment: dial, has that meaning I think.

Comment: Aligned like a watch (or clock) face seems to work adequately.

Comment: Aligned like what parts of a watch face? Please could you describe the appropriate parts of your image in the text of your question?

Comment: [Watch face](https://www.houseofwatches.co.uk/swatch-mens-once-again-watch-gb743) is really ambiguous, so that's fairly obviously not the term to use.

Comment: **Please do not answer in comments. Write an answer.**

Comment: Yeah, I realize that watch face is pretty ambiguous. What I'm referring to is the orientation of each element. On the left-hand side, each element retains it's original orientation (facing up), but on the right-hand side, each element is facing outwards, similar how the hour markers are aligned on a watch face. I was wondering if there is a more concrete expression to describe elements that face outwards ... when arranged in a circle... Even when describing it, I feel like I'm searching for words.

Comment: Actually, I've never seen a watch or clock laid out like you have on the **right**! Maybe there are some, but most have the numerals _upright_ (I assume the arrows signify which way is "up" for orientation), as given on the **left**. As given below, "radial orientation" would be good enough for the purpose of describing the right-hand layout.

Comment: @PhilPerry I've very rarely seen clocks with Roman numerals laid out that way (e.g [Big Ben's clock](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/93/Clock_Tower_-_Palace_of_Westminster%2C_London_-_May_2007.jpg)).  With ordinary Arabic numerals the fact that the "6" would be inverted would seem particularly mean and confusing.  I'm not saying Arabic numerals are never laid out like this on a clock face, but it would be abnormal

Comment: @ChrisH OK, maybe some with Roman numerals, but Arabic (decimal) numbers would be too easy to confuse (6 vs 9). Come to think of it, I may have seen some where 4 through 8 are radial, but reversed (up is "inwards") from 10 through 2. We're still assuming here that the arrows signify "up".

Comment: @PhilPerry yes.  I think from the acceptance of the top answer, arrows=up, i.e. radial is what the OP wanted.  A few other types of dial tilt the numbers, but they tend to span considerably less than 180° so the numbers are almost upright but slanted.  Unfortunately the room full of measuring kit I'm in is too modern to find an example

Comment: @ChrisH I was far too ambiguous with both my question and my follow-up comment. With the hour markers, I was referring to the symbols (usually rectangles) on a clock that show the hours and minutes, not the numbers themselves. That was a lesson for me to be more precise in the future, maybe the graphic with the arrows was also misleading (since the symbols on a clock technically have no side facing 'up').

Comment: @Alex fair enough.  I think many of us saw the boxes as placeholders, anyway it looks like we got to the right answer

Comment: Are your hours 90 minutes long? Or does the hour hand go round three times a day?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The arrows in the image on the right are **radial**. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/radial) has

> **radial**
> <sub>ADJECTIVE</sub>
>
> **1** Of or arranged like rays or the radii of a circle; diverging in lines from a common centre.
>
> *Seasoned logs will be light to the touch and will have radial cracks from the centre to the outside of the wood.*

As an adverb you can say

> The elements are arranged radially.

Comment: Thank you, radial describes what I was looking for, since the elements on the right-hand side 'spread' from a central point.

Comment: And you could also reasonably say that the arrows **radiate** from the centre, providing you are not in a context where that would be understood as the physics phenomenon.

Comment: I personally would say "arranged radially, facing outward" for the arrangement of the blocks, as they could also face inward and still be considered radially arranged. Though I'm not sure that "arranged in a circle, facing outward" wouldn't work just as well.

Comment: Backing up @trlkly, I'd simply say "facing out". Depends how technical you want to be; I think a lot of people would have no idea what "radial" means.